# Render vertices using opengl from c# code

Tags: c#, .net, opengl

I have been working on XNA for quite some time, but was asked to write a code to use OpenGL to render an obj file, as part of an assignment. I have written the code to read vertex and other information from obj file, and stored those values in arrays.

Now, I just want a way to render the vertices. After a bit of research, I got the CsGL framework, and added reference to those dlls in the project. I am unable to continue from here, as when I use `Gl.glclear();` function, project hangs. I checked intellitrace and even the call stack, but can't find anything.

I guess, I am supposed to initialize something else, before I can clear the buffer or start drawing anything. But, I am unable to find any tutorial about the same. I need to get just one point rendered on screen. Can anyone help me write the code for the same?

Comment: Some code samples maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples of using CsGL are avaliable from here [CsGL Official Examples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csgl/files/CsGLExamples/0.9.1/)  and [Legacy Nehe Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/) see the bottom of each tutorial for the sample CsGL C# code and [another basic tutorial](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3930/opengl-and-c-part-1/).

The reason your project hangs when call glcear (which clears what you tell it to usually the screen and the depth buffer) is probably because either OpenGL or the screen or the depth buffer were not properly initialised / setup according to OpenGL.

See the linked examples for how to initial OpenGL / OpenGL context before drawing anything.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Was a bit swamped. Anyways, thanks for the examples. Let me try those, and come back to you.

Comment: Ok, checked the examples. Looks a great point to start with. Although, it seems like too much work to just get a blank screen. God, XNA was so easy.